# Android Prevent system to kill application if service running

Tags: android, multithreading, service

My application can start a local service to do download task in background (in thread). 
If all the activities of my application are destroy (if user press back on all of them for example), the system kills my application even if the local service is still running. 
How can I prevent that in order the application stopped only when the service finished the download ?

Comment: Are you using Service or Thread?

Comment: It should not do that. could you please show your code? specifically the service and the way you are starting it?